# concatenation truncating numberic value

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

in a cell J21 I have entered a numeric value 1.10000. The cell is set to numeric value with 5 decimal places.

When using concatenate =CONCATENATE("=CONCATENATE("@ £/€ rate: ",(J21))  in another cell elsewhere on the sheet, I get the result "@ £/€ rate: 1.1 therefore truncating the full value shown (1.10000).

Is there a way to concatenate the full value including any zeros?

Following the answer provided by @marikamitsos the following results were produced:

[image]

The issue seems clearly at the door of limitations to CONCATENATE since a straight reference to the cell containing the value gives the result required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this instance, neither suggested solution works:
>
> =`CONCATENATE`("@ £/€ rate: ",(J2))
>
> or in this one:
>
> ="@ £/€ rate: "&J2
>
> as both solutions still truncate the numeric result.

After more detailed experimentation what does work on my system when concatenating a numeric value alongside other text in this context is:

=CONCATENATE("@ £/€ rate: ",text(J21,"0.00000"))

Combined functions used (converting a number to text):

[CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)

[TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)

Comment: I am afraid you jump to the wrong conclusions thus also misleading the readers. Please read my updated answer.

Comment: My accepted answer in no way misleads the readers. It is factual and I'm very sorry that your offerings did not work for me.

Comment: Please explain what warning is necessary. Will readers' systems break if they use this formula? Warning people about non-existent problems is not what I would expect from any SE site.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer updated

*(as a reply to your [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/147879/2), [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/147879/concatenation-truncating-numberic-value/147881#comment134495_147881) as well as your own [accepted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/147894).)*

**I am afraid you jump to the wrong conclusions thus also misleading the readers.**

Why? Because...

> Just as in this hidden/missing text.
>
> **1**. In your statement *"in a cell J21 I have a set value 1.10000"* you merely reveal what is present in the cell.
>  **2**. Further more you fail to show how this value was placed there (whether manually or as a result of a formula/script).
> **3**. Not even how it is formatted or presented.
> **4**. More so whether the value is a number or text.
> **5**. Needless to mention the reference to its `Horizontal alignment` (in your later added image)
> **6**. Finally, you do not take into consideration any of the aforementioned points even after your edited question or more so in your accepted answer.
>
> The above may seem to be insignificant, still truly essential and should not be missed for the right set of conclusions.

Thus you arrive to a wrong/partial assumption

*"concatenate doesn't work in ...as both solutions still truncate the numeric result."*

**All given solutions (yours and mine) work.**

### **The correct conclusion**

**The issue does NOT lay on `CONCATENATE` itself.

Depending on the situation different solutions may apply.**

*When asking a question please share all relevant info and even better share an editable sheet so you can be easier helped.*

---

**Original answer**

---

You should change your formula syntax to

```
=CONCATENATE("@ £/€ rate: ",(J2))
```

You could also use

```
="@ £/€ rate: "&J2
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the first solution still returns 1.1 not 1.10000

Comment: *"...first solution still returns 1.1 not 1.10000"* Does that mean that the second works? Could there be an issue with your locale? In any case, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. Also. Remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please read my updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but the simple fact remains that your answer did not correct my issue but my own accepted solution does and the correct result is now displayed in the target cell.  I see no reason to change my selected accepted answer, but once again, thanks for your input.

Comment: *"I see no reason to change my selected accepted answer"* never expected or wanted you to. They are excellent examples of what to avoid.  *"The simple fact is I appreciate your efforts but...the target cell"* I see that you completely missed my points. :(